# GridView values not changing on value change of the combobox it is bound to

Tags: asp.net

I have two 2 dropdown lists D1 and D2 and a griview G1. 
D2 gets updated when selected value in D1 changes, through a postback.
G1 gets updated when selected value in D2 changes.

The problem is, Data in G1 gets refreshed only if I explicitely change the value in D2. When I change value in D1, D2 automatically gets refreshed, but G1 shows the old value. How to make G1 refresh?

I added a G1.DataBind() inside D1_SelectedIndexChanged, but still it retains the old value.

Comment: Are you using declarative datasources(e.g. SqlDataSource) or programmatic(codebehind)?

Comment: I am using declarative datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Becoz your Gridview is inside an updatepanel whose behavior is conditional. So inside D1_SelectedIndexChanged write gridviewUpdatePanel.update();

Comment: I am really new to this and I had I nfact tried out updatepanel. It did not work even after changing the updatemode of update panel to conditional and updating it. I even tried databinding G1.DataBind() after doing this, still it is not working. ` UpdatePanel1.UpdateMode =UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional; UpdatePanel1.Update(); GridView2.DataBind(); `